# Error when using sortByFst: Variable not in scope

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> sortByFst = sortBy (\x y -> fst x `compare` fst y)

<interactive>:7:13: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      sortBy :: (((), b0) -> ((), b1) -> Ordering) -> t
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You tried to call a function named [`sortBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy), but GHCi wasn't aware of any such function. This happened because `sortBy` is in [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) and not [`Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html). To use anything from modules other than `Prelude`, you need to import them, so doing `import Data.List` will make your code work.

Also, for what you're doing, `sortBy` is the wrong tool for the job. Your lambda is equivalent to `comparing fst`, and `sortBy (comparing fst)` is the same as `sortOn fst`. Thus, `sortByFst = sortOn fst` does the same thing as your code, but is much simpler and faster.

Comment: I doubt it will be faster.  After all `sortOn fst` has to keep tuples `(a, (a,b))` around in order to avoid recomputing the the "expensive" projection `fst`...  (But in general I am super in favor of the *`On` instead of *`By` functions, also for correctness reasons)

Comment: The answer by Joseph work great, although I don't know if it would be faster or not. And thanks to luqui for the comment.